# Children's audio books good for listening practice?

Tags: learning, resources, comprehension

I'm looking for a website with free audio recordings of Japanese children books. I found one a long time ago but alas I lost my bookmark to that site. I'm planning to go through those books since it'll be easier to follow the japanese they speak as opposed to listening to japanese talk shows and such for adults. Is this a good way to work on my listening?

Anyone have a recommendation?

Comment: this question might be perceived as off-topic because it is not specifically about Japanese language.  Changed the title to make it a little clearer

Answer (score 4):

I would think it would be ok though they sometime use pronunciations that are easier for kids to understand, informal japanese, and words typically used by kids.

I'm not quite sure what your level is, but watching Love (renai) dramas with japanese subtitles would be my recommendation to improve your listening.

Another option is what is called Shadow books, where you read along with a CD.  Helps with your japanese reading as well.  These books are usually broken up into levels corresponding to the JLPT levels.

Comment: Do you happen to know the ISBN for the shadow books you mentioned? I'd like to find some of them.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%89%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%92%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86-%E5%88%9D%E3%80%9C%E4%B8%AD%E7%B4%9A%E7%B7%A8-%E6%96%8E%E8%97%A4-%E4%BB%81%E5%BF%97/dp/4874243541/ref=pd_sim_b2

ISBN-10: 4874243541
ISBN-13: 978-4874243541

Comment: I'm at a pretty low level, I can understand lots of basic conversations, I might get about 50-60% comprehension in a renai. That's why I wanted to work with audio childrens book. I'm not good enough at reading to shadow haha...